# N finding the mean length of time Ws - M/M/1 System with finite capacity

Tags: probability, queueing-theory

This is the answer I got but I'm not confident with it. So the question is find the mean length of time a customer spends in the shop (Ws).

We know that a customer enters a shop at random at a rate of 20 per hour
and the capacity of the shop is 4 customers, and any additional customers are turned away. Ans the mean service time is 3 mins.

In a previous question I worked out that Ls equals 2

So this is what I think you do

Ws= $\frac{Ls}{λeff}$

From research I know that λeff= $\sum_{n=o}^N λnPn$ = $\sum_{n=o}^{N-1} λ(1-PN)$ (since λN=0)
because previously we worked out that ρ=1,we now have to use that Pn=$\frac{1}{N+1}$

Therefore
λeff= 20(1-PN) (since λN=0)

λeff = 20(1- $\frac{1}{N + 1}$)

λeff = 20(1- $\frac{1}{4+ 1}$)

λeff = 20(1- $\frac{1}{5}$)

λeff = 20(1- $\frac{4}{5}$)

λeff = 16

Therefore
Ws=  $\frac{Ls}{λeff}$

Ws=  $\frac{2}{16}$

OR Because we don't know what PN stands for can we just do it this way?

λeff= $\sum_{n=o}^{N-1} λnPn$

λeff= $\sum_{n=o}^{N-1} 20Pn$

Pn = $\frac{1}{N+1}$ because ρ=1 therefore Pn= $\frac{1}{5}$

λeff= $\sum_{n=o}^{N-1}(20)(1/5)$

λeff= $\sum_{n=o}^3 (20)(1/5)$

λeff= $\sum_{n=o}^3 4$

λeff= 12

Thus Ws= $\frac{2}{12}$

Some help would be much appreicated.

Comment: Please improve the MathJax formatting

Comment: I have improved it to the best of my knowledge

Answer (score 1):

Since $\lambda=\mu$, the detailed balance equations $\lambda \pi_j=\mu\pi_{j+1}$ imply that $\pi_j=\pi_{j+1}$, and hence $\pi_j=\frac15$ for $j=0,1,2,3,4$. The mean number of customers in the system is then
$$
L = \sum_{j=0}^n j\pi_j = \frac15 \sum_{j=1}^4 j = 2,
$$
and the effective arrival rate
$$
\lambda_{\mathrm{eff}} = \lambda(1-\pi_4) = 20\left(1-\frac15\right) = 16.
$$
We use Little's Law to compute the mean sojourn time:
$$
W = \frac L{\lambda_{\mathrm{eff}}} = \frac2{16}=\frac18.
$$